Inequalities and GIF
I had the inequality as follows,
$$|[|x|-7]|- 5 < 0$$
I wanted to know the range of $x$ that satisfies this inequality.
Here, $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function and $|\cdot|$ denotes the modulus function.
Using $|x| < a\implies-a<x<a$, I got
$$-5 < [|x|-7] < 5$$
Now, I needed to remove GIF function, which got me confused.
Using some online sources, I got this to be,
$$-4 ≤ |x| - 7 < 5$$
But why is the inequality changed only on $-5$, not on $5$? I think it should be,
$$-4 ≤ |x| - 7 ≤ 4$$
It doesn't make sense to me why $5$ is not changed. If you took say value of $4.3$, which is $<5$, you get its GIF to be $=5$, which is not in the original inequality.
So how to properly manipulate inequalities consisting functions like GIF?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

The GIF of $4.3$ is $4$, not $5$. Recall that the GIF of $x$ is the largest integer smaller than $x$. So, we have the following ($n$ is any integer):

$[x]<n$ implies $x<n$.
$[x]\le n$ implies $x<n+1$.
$[x]>n$ implies $x\ge n+1$.
$[x]\ge n$ implies $x\ge n$.

Hope this helps. :)
